# ImportError: No module named 'gensim'

Tags: python, gensim

I have installed gensim for Windows by the command:

> conda install -c anaconda gensim

I have an environment py35. I'm trying to run a Python script using the import statement: `from gensim.models import Word2Vec` where there is an error `ImportError: No module named 'gensim'`. Any idea what to be done?

Comment: My idea is that you've probably not installed gensim. Check it's in the right environment and you're in the right environment. `conda list` and `print(sys.executable)` might help you

Comment: There are two environments - Anaconda3 and py35. Through the Anaconda Navigator, after selecting Anaconda3, gensim is showing in the list but not in case of py35. My working environment is py35.

Comment: If your working environment is py35, then you'd do something like `py35 -m pip install gensim to install gensim` in that environment. I am not sure if you start your py35 by typing py35 or python3.5, but i am guessing you got the idea.

Comment: @raj 'py35' command not found error.

Comment: @PSNayak i didn't mean you to directly write `py35`. Please read the comment thoroughly. In place of py35 you have to substitute the python call that actually starts py35 environment as you mentioned before.

Comment: I tried re-installing the `gensim` package by using the following command - `conda install -c conda-forge gensim`. It is working now. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the package as it does not come with Python. This will do the job:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```